# bash process uses 90% CPU, comes back on computer restart

Tags: macos, bash, process

I’ve replaced the old HDD of my late 2008 unibody MacBook (8 GB of RAM, running OS X 10.7.4) with an OCZ Vertex 3 SSD. After doing this, I've installed Lion and restored my data from a Time Machine backup.

Everything is fine, except for a process named “bash” that permanently uses about 90 % CPU.

If I kill it via Activity Monitor, everything goes back to normal, but unfortunately the process comes back every time I restart the computer.

I've tried do zap the PRAM, reinstall 10.7.4 from the combo package, and even simply wait for more than 2 hours, but the problem is still here.

Comment: Which user runs that process? What additional information do you get through Activity Monitor? Anything particular in `ps -ef` about it?

Comment: It comes straight from my account. /
/bin/bash
/usr/lib/dyld
/private/var/db/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64
/dev/null
->0xffffff8012ae4810
->0xffffff8012ae4810
->0xffffff8011d30180
/usr/bin/stkLaunchAgent.sh

Comment: Hmm... you should check out what is with that stkLaunchAgend.sh . From  Google, STK could be some Oracle thing, some game (Super Tux Kit), for different development frameworks (Synthesis ToolKit, Standard Templating Kit). That dyld is the dynamic linker, which has something to do with loading libraries. Maybe you have some problems with the alternate caching of a process or something. I'm no expert, but I hope I gave you a lead.

Comment: I have exactly same issue, and I realize the stkLaunchAgnet.sh come form an app call "Send to Kindle".Problem solved after I uninstall "Send to Kindle" by it's uninstaller.

Comment: Whoever wonders what stkLaunchAgent is: This script is part of Amazon's "Send To Kindle" app.

Answer (score 9):

Until replaced by *zsh* in macOS 10.15, *[bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29)* was the standard shell of the Mac operating systems – i.e. the standard program to interface with the operating system’s *[Darwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_%28operating_system%29)* underpinnings (technically, `/bin/sh` is the standard shell on a Mac, but that was a copy of `/bin/bash` from OS X 10.3 to macOS 10.15). It is the process that is launched when you open a *Terminal.app* window – an interactive shell.

*bash* can also be launched without a terminal window – a non-interactive shell –, for instance to execute *shell scripts*, often denoted by the file suffix `.sh`. That is the case here – *bash* is running the script `/usr/bin/stkLaunchAgent.sh`, and something in this script is keeping your system busy.

Now, as of the time this question was asked, `/usr/bin/stkLaunchAgent.sh` is not part of an OS X install – it is some kind of third party addition and as such is not present on my system, meaning I can only guess, but I’d say:

- from its name part “LaunchAgent” and the fact it starts with your system, that it is triggered by a *LaunchAgent* – a small definition file used by OS X’ *launchd*, the system mechanism for starting scripts and non-interactive programs on schedule, boot or other events. That part I‘d qualify as an educated guess.
- from the fact your troubles began with the installation of your Vertex SSD, and the fact that the crucial difference between SSDs and HDs is the first do not take kindly to defragmentation and similar low-level interventions into their structure, that the script launched by the agent in question might be trying to do some operation on the drive the Vertex SSD does not accept – which keeps the script running and *bash* busy. Now, *that* part is only a wild, wild guess, but…

**How to find out what the script does:**

Open a Terminal window and do `open -e /usr/bin/stkLaunchAgent.sh` to have a peek into the shell script (that command will open it in TextEdit – terminate it in Activity Monitor first) – that should give you the means to see what exactly is running.

**How to get rid of it:**

You’ll have to get rid of the LaunchAgent, if it is indeed one. *launchd* LaunchAgent files are in *plist* format and found in

- `~/Library/LaunchAgents` – for the current user account only
- `/Library/LaunchAgents` – for all user accounts
- `/System/Library/LaunchAgents` – system level agents (should not by rights be found here!)

They are usually named in reverse domain notation (`tld.domain.process.plist`). Depending if the user account of your runaway `bash` is yours or not, you should look in one of the first two locations above for a likely plist (if you have Xcode installed, you can QuickLook them easily). The correct procedure to stop it is to remove it from *launchd*’s process list through

```
launchctl unload tld.domain.process
```

which will unload and stop the process (note you omit the `plist` suffix).

There is also a GUI for handling *launchd* files, [Peter Borg’s *Lingon*](http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/lingon/id411211026?mt=12) (make sure to get “Lingon”, not “Lingon 3”, which is a dumbed down version safe for vanilla use), which might be more convenient than manually rooting through the file locations.

**Background:**

- [*bash on OS X* by David Miller](http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2004/02/24/bash.html) (from 2004, but still a good introduction)
- [*launchd* article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd)

Answer (score 4):

I looked inside the file and learned its part of the Save to Kindle application that I installed a few weeks ago. The app has an uninstaller in /Applications, so I did that instead of deleting the .sh directly. Worked.

Comment: Uninstalling Save to Kindle fixed this for me too. The cause seems to be a combination of that app and restoring from a Time Machine backup on Lion, because it was working fine for weeks and it was only after I migrated to a new laptop using Time Machine that the problem began.

Comment: Removing the "Send to Kindle" program will indeed solve the problem. If you want to continue to use the program reinstall it again and it should work fine with the SSD. I had to restore my system with Time Machine and the bash process/issue returned. Once I reinstalled the program it no longer presented itself.

Comment: Same issue here, good find. I uninstalled and the prob went away, fan stopped spinning and computer cooled down. I then re-installed and things are fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after migrating my system to a Crucial M4 SSD. I "solved" it by deleting /usr/bin/stkLaunchAgent.sh as there were no launch demons directly related to the file.

I'd still like to know where that file came from and why this occurred...

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem on my computer by using `chown` to own the communication pipe present in `/var/spool/stkPrinter/username/stkPipe`.

The problem occurs because the ownership (maybe the permissions too?) of the pipe changes after migrating to a new drive. The script `/usr/bin/stkLaunchAgent.sh` does have some basic permission/ownership checking built in, but it obviously doesn't do it well enough. It ends up in the `while true` loop trying to access the pipe and the logs get completely overtaken by error messages.

I wouldn't even have noticed this if I didn't notice that my Time Machine backups were being inexplicably large, that's when I looked at the system logs and saw millions of lines complaining about the same thing. The log file `/var/spool/stkPrinter/username/stkPrint.log` was 15GB large!