# How do I find out why a bash script starts on my Mac?

Tags: mac, bash, troubleshooting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bash process uses 90% CPU, comes back on computer restart](https://superuser.com/questions/423772/bash-process-uses-90-cpu-comes-back-on-computer-restart)

A bash script is starting on my Macbook air.  (I bought it yesterday).

The script is taking about 20% of my cpu.

It starts every time I restart the machine.

I want to know what it's running ... but I don't know how to find out.

[I can very slowly find my way around terminal, but I've not done unix stuff for about 15 years ... and then I was no expert.]

Comment: What script is it? There might be a very good reason why it's running.

Comment: Kenneth: that's what I'm trying to figure out.  I can see it in Activity Monitor, it's taking 20% of my CPU, and I have no idea why.

Comment: How do you know it is running and which user is running it?

Comment: Kenneth: I got the macbook air, brand new yesterday, and I've installed a lot of stuff (just apps, nothing special).  And now this has happened.

Comment: Not enough detail in the question. Why do you assume it's a bash script? How are you measuring 20% CPU usage - is the script staying alive long enough for you to see it in Activity Monitor?

Comment: -1, this question is unclear. Please at least tell us the name of that script. It's impossible to even guess what happens if you can't supply that important piece of information. What does the *Activity Monitor* show about that script? Please [edit] your question and add more info. Maybe also show the output of `ps auxww` related to that script.

Comment: sorry ... I was asking how to find out what the script was.

Comment: As a new user ... I can't figure out how to close this question down.

Comment: I've figured out the answer: it was the Amazon Send to Kindle app, incorrectly uninstalled. Thanks

Comment: Well I assumed since you knew that it was a bash script that you already found out where to look, sorry! Either way, you could answer your own question, or we'll rather close it as *too localized* (in that sense, irreproducible, since this is probably never going to happen to someone else).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just left Terminal.app running when you shut down your Mac? In Lion open apps are reopened when you reboot

Comment: I figured it out (thanks to this: bash process uses 90% CPU, comes back on computer restart).

It was Amazon's Send To Kindle application. I installed it, but it didn't uninstall a script. I've reinstalled it and now the problem has gone away.

Thanks everyone.